# How many numbers (up to $2^n$) is the power of any number (exponent greater than $1$)?

Tags: number-theory

How many numbers (up to $2^n$) is the power of any number (exponent greater than $1$)?

All natural numbers.

Is the number of numbers growing exponentially along with $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of squares below or equal to $2^n$ is exactly
$$
\lfloor \sqrt{2^n}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{2}^n\rfloor\approx 1.41^n
$$
which grows exponentially in $n$. If you include higher powers into the count, then it will get larger, but it's still clearly bounded above by $2^n$. We conclude that the number of pure powers below $2^n$ grows exponentially in $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The exact number of perfect powers up to $N=2^n$ is
$$ 1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \mu(k)\left(\lfloor N^{1/k}\rfloor -1\right)=1+\sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor \operatorname{ld} N\rfloor} \mu(k)\left(\lfloor N^{1/k}\rfloor -1\right)
$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. As Arthur pointed out, this sum is $\sim \sqrt N$ and hence grows exponentially in $n$.